# implementing routing into my wcf service

Tags: wcf, routes

I have clients that upload files to my server using a wcf service with streaming. The code on the client is something like this (omitting some details):

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + ipAddress + ":5000/DataUploader");
ChannelFactory<IDataUploader> channel = new ChannelFactory<IDataUploader>(binding, address);
IDataUploader uploader = channel.CreateChannel();

try
{
    uploader.Upload(msg);
    ConsoleText.Record("The file was sent...\n");
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    ConsoleText.Record("The file was not sent...\n" + "Interrupted connection...\n");
}
finally
{
    uploadStream.Close();
    ((IClientChannel)uploader).Close();
}
```

I want to implement a routing service between server and client, the routing service would be something like this:

```
private static void ConfigureRouterViaCode(ServiceHost serviceHost)
{
    string clientAddress = "http://localhost:5000/DataUploader";
    string routerAddress = "http://localhost:5000/RouterService";

    Binding routerBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
    Binding clientBinding = new WSHttpBinding();

    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRequestReplyRouter), routerBinding, routerAddress);

    ContractDescription contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IRequestReplyRouter));
    ServiceEndpoint client = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, clientBinding, new EndpointAddress(clientAddress));

    RoutingConfiguration rc = new RoutingConfiguration();

    List<ServiceEndpoint> endpointList = new List<ServiceEndpoint>();
    endpointList.Add(client);

    rc.FilterTable.Add(new MatchAllMessageFilter(), endpointList);

    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new RoutingBehavior(rc));
}
```

It's confused how I can connect my client to the routing service first. Is this a good approach?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your approach is correct. On the client, change the address pointing to the routing service, leaving all other settings as they were. I suggest you study http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx or find some demo routing implementations.